# Embed a matplotlib plot in a pyqt5 gui

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I'm working with PyQt5 trying to generate a GUI for my data analysis tool. My problem is that I don't understand how to embed a matplotlib plot with full functionality.

All of the tutorials about PyQt5 and how to embed matplotlib show a very simple way where they create all of the graphical object directly in the code. I don't want to do that because my GUI was generated with Qt Designer. I created a QWidget to plot data in it. Therefore, I import the UI file in the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import numpy as np

from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel, QGridLayout, QWidget, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QInputDialog, QLineEdit, QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, uic

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('QT5Agg')

import matplotlib.pylab as plt

from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtCore, QtWidgets, is_pyqt5
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvas,     NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):

        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()

        self.ui = uic.loadUi('test.ui', self) 

        # test data
        data = np.array([0.7,0.7,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.9,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5])        
        fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
        bins = np.arange(0.6, 1.62, 0.02)
        n1, bins1, patches1 = ax1.hist(data, bins, alpha=0.6, density=False, cumulative=False)

        # plot
        self.plotWidget = FigureCanvas(fig)        

        # add toolbar
        self.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.BottomToolBarArea, NavigationToolbar(self.plotWidget, self))        

    #########################################

    # show window
    self.show() 

    #########################################

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This is test.ui file created by Qt Designer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>772</width>
    <height>650</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="plotWidge" native="true">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>20</x>
     <y>20</y>
     <width>721</width>
     <height>571</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

What happened is that I can see a toolbar in my window but now data. I can use the "save" icon to save the plot as an image. I think that I'm creating a second instance of a widget object that is not correlated to the one I created in Qt Designer.

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @eyllanesc I added a full example

Comment: share test.ui..

Comment: Widgets need to be added to a layout in pyqt. I don't see you doing this for the FigureCanvas anywhere in the code.

Comment: @eyllanesc I added the ui code

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I saw this all the time when the objects where created in the code directly. But I don't know how to do that when I'm loading the external UI file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are confusing that you have created a widget called `plotWidge` in Qt Designer and you doing `self.plotWidget = FigureCanvas(fig)` are replacing it (even if the names coincide that action is not the one done), so that it does not cause confusion change `plotWidge` to `content_plot` in Qt Designer so the `plotWidget` must be placed in `content_plot` with the help of a layout.

**test.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>772</width>
    <height>650</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="content_plot" native="true">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>20</x>
     <y>20</y>
     <width>721</width>
     <height>571</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

***.py**

```
import sys
import numpy as np

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, uic

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('QT5Agg')

import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvas 
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('test.ui', self) 
        # test data
        data = np.array([0.7,0.7,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.9,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5])        
        fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
        bins = np.arange(0.6, 1.62, 0.02)
        n1, bins1, patches1 = ax1.hist(data, bins, alpha=0.6, density=False, cumulative=False)
        # plot
        self.plotWidget = FigureCanvas(fig)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.content_plot)  
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)      
        lay.addWidget(self.plotWidget)
        # add toolbar
        self.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.BottomToolBarArea, NavigationToolbar(self.plotWidget, self))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The GUI design becomes more flexible with the use of super() in Python. After creating the GUI (.ui) using Qt designer we can further extend its functionality by converting it to python (.py) file: pyuic5 -x test.ui -o test.py

For those looking for a solution that starts from at Qt designer and ends at something like this tutorial [code](https://youtu.be/1q3Z2clyIEQ):

[image]

The test.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
      <item>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Select Theme</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QComboBox" name="comboBox"/>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Open</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>40</width>
          <height>20</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="0">
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
      <item>
       <spacer name="verticalSpacer">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>20</width>
          <height>40</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuFile">
    <property name="title">
     <string>File</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="actionOpen_csv_file"/>
    <addaction name="actionExit"/>
   </widget>
   <addaction name="menuFile"/>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
  <action name="actionOpen_csv_file">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Open csv file</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionExit">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Exit</string>
   </property>
  </action>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

and the complete edited test.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg, NavigationToolbar2QT as Navi
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import sip # can be installed : pip install sip

# We require a canvas class
import platform

# Use NSURL as a workaround to pyside/Qt4 behaviour for dragging and dropping on OSx
op_sys = platform.system()
if op_sys == 'Darwin':
    from Foundation import NSURL

class MatplotlibCanvas(FigureCanvasQTAgg):
    def __init__(self,parent=None, dpi = 120):
        fig = Figure(dpi = dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        super(MatplotlibCanvas,self).__init__(fig)
        fig.tight_layout()
        
        

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1440, 1000)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.comboBox)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout.addItem(self.spacerItem1)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionOpen_csv_file = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen_csv_file.setObjectName("actionOpen_csv_file")
        self.actionExit = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionExit.setObjectName("actionExit")
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionOpen_csv_file)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionExit)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        
        self.filename = ''
        self.canv = MatplotlibCanvas(self)
        self.df = []
        
        self.toolbar = Navi(self.canv,self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
        
        self.themes = ['bmh', 'classic', 'dark_background', 'fast', 
        'fivethirtyeight', 'ggplot', 'grayscale', 'seaborn-bright',
         'seaborn-colorblind', 'seaborn-dark-palette', 'seaborn-dark', 
         'seaborn-darkgrid', 'seaborn-deep', 'seaborn-muted', 'seaborn-notebook',
         'seaborn-paper', 'seaborn-pastel', 'seaborn-poster', 'seaborn-talk',
         'seaborn-ticks', 'seaborn-white', 'seaborn-whitegrid', 'seaborn',
         'Solarize_Light2', 'tableau-colorblind10']
         
        self.comboBox.addItems(self.themes)
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.getFile)
        self.comboBox.currentIndexChanged['QString'].connect(self.Update)
        self.actionExit.triggered.connect(MainWindow.close)
        self.actionOpen_csv_file.triggered.connect(self.getFile)
        
    def Update(self,value):
        print("Value from Combo Box:",value)
        plt.clf()
        plt.style.use(value)
        try:
            self.horizontalLayout.removeWidget(self.toolbar)
            self.verticalLayout.removeWidget(self.canv)
            
            sip.delete(self.toolbar)
            sip.delete(self.canv)
            self.toolbar = None
            self.canv = None
            self.verticalLayout.removeItem(self.spacerItem1)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            pass
        self.canv = MatplotlibCanvas(self)
        self.toolbar = Navi(self.canv,self.centralwidget)
        
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.canv)
        
        self.canv.axes.cla()
        ax = self.canv.axes
        self.df.plot(ax = self.canv.axes)
        legend = ax.legend()
        legend.set_draggable(True)
        
        ax.set_xlabel('X axis')
        ax.set_ylabel('Y axis')
        ax.set_title(self.Title)
        
        self.canv.draw()
        
        
        
        
    
    def getFile(self):
        """ This function will get the address of the csv file location
            also calls a readData function 
        """
        self.filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(filter = "csv (*.csv)")[0]
        print("File :", self.filename)
        self.readData()
    
    def readData(self):
        """ This function will read the data using pandas and call the update
            function to plot
        """
        import os
        base_name = os.path.basename(self.filename)
        self.Title = os.path.splitext(base_name)[0]
        print('FILE',self.Title )
        self.df = pd.read_csv(self.filename,encoding = 'utf-8').fillna(0)
        self.Update(self.themes[0]) # lets 0th theme be the default : bmh
    

    
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Select Theme"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open"))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.actionOpen_csv_file.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open csv file"))
        self.actionExit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```