# Updating matplotlib in pyqt5 widget

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I have created a UI in qt designer and load it using UIC. I make updates to the UI so I dont want to convert the UI to python. I am using the following post to embed my PLT:
[Embed a matplotlib plot in a pyqt5 gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53157230/embed-a-matplotlib-plot-in-a-pyqt5-gui)

However, I have tried updating the graph and have failed using the following different methods:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>728</width>
    <height>429</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QWidget" name="graphWidget" native="true">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>551</width>
      <height>351</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="palette">
     <palette>
      <active>
       <colorrole role="WindowText">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>0</red>
          <green>0</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Button">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>255</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>255</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Light">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>255</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>255</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Midlight">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>255</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>255</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Dark">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>127</red>
          <green>127</green>
          <blue>127</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Mid">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>170</red>
          <green>170</green>
          <blue>170</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Text">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>0</red>
          <green>0</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="BrightText">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>255</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>255</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="ButtonText">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>0</red>
          <green>0</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Base">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>255</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>255</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Window">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>255</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>255</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Shadow">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>0</red>
          <green>0</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="AlternateBase">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>255</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>255</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="ToolTipBase">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>255</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>220</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="ToolTipText">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>0</red>
          <green>0</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="PlaceholderText">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="128">
          <red>0</red>
          <green>0</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
      </active>
      <inactive>
       <colorrole role="WindowText">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>0</red>
          <green>0</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Button">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>255</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>255</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Light">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>255</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>255</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Midlight">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>255</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>255</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Dark">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>127</red>
          <green>127</green>
          <blue>127</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Mid">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>170</red>
          <green>170</green>
          <blue>170</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Text">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>0</red>
          <green>0</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="BrightText">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>255</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>255</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="ButtonText">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>0</red>
          <green>0</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Base">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>255</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>255</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Window">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>255</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>255</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Shadow">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>0</red>
          <green>0</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="AlternateBase">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>255</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>255</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="ToolTipBase">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>255</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>220</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="ToolTipText">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>0</red>
          <green>0</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="PlaceholderText">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="128">
          <red>0</red>
          <green>0</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
      </inactive>
      <disabled>
       <colorrole role="WindowText">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>127</red>
          <green>127</green>
          <blue>127</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Button">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>255</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>255</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Light">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>255</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>255</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Midlight">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>255</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>255</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Dark">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>127</red>
          <green>127</green>
          <blue>127</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Mid">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>170</red>
          <green>170</green>
          <blue>170</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Text">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>127</red>
          <green>127</green>
          <blue>127</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="BrightText">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>255</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>255</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="ButtonText">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>127</red>
          <green>127</green>
          <blue>127</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Base">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>255</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>255</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Window">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>255</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>255</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Shadow">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>0</red>
          <green>0</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="AlternateBase">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>255</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>255</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="ToolTipBase">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>255</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>220</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="ToolTipText">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>0</red>
          <green>0</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="PlaceholderText">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="128">
          <red>0</red>
          <green>0</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
      </disabled>
     </palette>
    </property>
    <property name="autoFillBackground">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="start">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>590</x>
      <y>30</y>
      <width>91</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Start</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="restart">
    <property name="enabled">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>590</x>
      <y>100</y>
      <width>91</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Restart</string>
    </property>
    <property name="checkable">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_7">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>730</x>
      <y>130</y>
      <width>171</width>
      <height>71</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
    <property name="alignment">
     <set>Qt::AlignLeading|Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignTop</set>
    </property>
    <property name="wordWrap">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="intervene">
    <property name="enabled">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>590</x>
      <y>170</y>
      <width>91</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Intervene</string>
    </property>
    <property name="checkable">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>728</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, uic
import pyqtgraph as pg
import sys  # We need sys so that we can pass argv to QApplication
import time
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi, voronoi_plot_2d

matplotlib.use('QT5Agg')


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Load the UI
        uic.loadUi('src\Main.ui', self)

        # Runs functions on button press
        self.start.clicked.connect(self.startfcn)

        # add toolbar
        # self.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.BottomToolBarArea, NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self))
    # This function is run when the start button is pushed
    def startfcn(self):
        sd = 20
        # rng(sd)
        numIterations = 1000
        samplingPeriod = 10
        xrange = 10  # region size
        yrange = 5
        n = 20  # number of robots (changing the number of robots is interesting)
        dt = 1
        maxSpeed = 8

        # Draw graph
        points = np.random.rand(10, 2)  # random points for Voronoi
        vor = Voronoi(points)  # Create Voronoi object
        fig = voronoi_plot_2d(vor)  # Make vor object into a plot object
        canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)  # create a mpl canvas obj
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.graphWidget)  # create layout in graph widget
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        lay.addWidget(canvas)  # add canvas obj to layout
        # all of these are attempts to update the graph
        canvas.draw()
        self.graphWidget.update()
        self.graphWidget.show()
        QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When pressing the start button, it should show a new random voronoi plot, which it does not.

I need it to update the graphWidget everytime the start button is pressed.

Comment: I'm not sure why the UI is so long, but its basically the main window and a qwidget called graphWidget, then some buttons

Comment: Pressing the button again should show a new random voronoi graph, which doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to change the `Figure` then you must create a new canvas so you will have to destroy the previous one:

```py
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.canvas = None

        uic.loadUi("Main.ui", self)
        self.canvas_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.graphWidget)
        self.canvas_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.start.clicked.connect(self.startfcn)

        # add toolbar
        # self.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.BottomToolBarArea, NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self))

    # This function is run when the start button is pushed
    def startfcn(self):
        # Draw graph
        points = np.random.rand(10, 2)  # random points for Voronoi
        vor = Voronoi(points)  # Create Voronoi object
        fig = voronoi_plot_2d(vor)  # Make vor object into a plot object

        if self.canvas is not None:
            self.canvas.deleteLater()

        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)

        self.canvas_layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
```

Another better option is to pass the axes to the `voronoi_plot_2d()` method through the "ax" argument:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, uic

import matplotlib
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar

import numpy as np

from scipy.spatial import Voronoi, voronoi_plot_2d

matplotlib.use("QT5Agg")


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure())

        uic.loadUi("Main.ui", self)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.graphWidget)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        lay.addWidget(self.canvas)

        self.start.clicked.connect(self.startfcn)

        self.ax = None

        # add toolbar
        # self.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.BottomToolBarArea, NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self))

    # This function is run when the start button is pushed
    def startfcn(self):
        if self.ax is None:
            self.ax = self.canvas.figure.subplots()
        # Draw graph
        points = np.random.rand(10, 2)  # random points for Voronoi
        vor = Voronoi(points)  # Create Voronoi object
        self.ax.clear()
        voronoi_plot_2d(vor, ax=self.ax)  # Make vor object into a plot object
        self.canvas.draw()


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: The first method will give you a warning about too many plots open. I implemented something like the seocond one. Also, the only useful MPL documentation I've been able to find: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt_sgskip.html

Comment: @bobthebuilder What tool gives you that warning?

Comment: Using pycharm, warning ouptuted on the terminal